# How to add additional value to an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, int

I am currently creating a program where the user can use a printer as long as that particular user has enough funds.

The current issue I am having is that if the user chooses to have colour printing instead of black and white then the price for each piece of paper goes up.

How do I add value to an already existing array?

Here is my code...

```
printers[0] = new Printer("printer1", 0.10M);
            printers[1] = new Printer("printer2", 0.08M);
            printers[2] = new Printer("printer3", 0.05M);
            printers[3] = new Printer("printer4", 0.15);
            printers[4] = new Printer("printer5", 0.09M);

            foreach (Printer r in mPrinters)
            {
                if (printer != null)
                    printerCombo.Items.Add(r.getName());
            }
```

Comment: use a List<T> instead

Comment: Arrays are of fixed size _by design_. If want a collection that you can add, remove, insert then look at the classes in `System.Collection.Generic` or `System.Collection.ObjectModel`

Answer (score 3):

Technically, you can [Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) the array:

```
 Array.Resize(ref printers, printers.Length + 1);

 printers[printers.Length - 1] = new Printer("printer6", 0.25M);
```

However, a much better approach is to change the collection type: *array* into `List<T>`:

```
 List<Printer> printers = new List<Printer>() {
   new Printer("printer1", 0.10M),
   new Printer("printer2", 0.08M),
   new Printer("printer3", 0.05M),
   new Printer("printer4", 0.15),
   new Printer("printer5", 0.09M), }; 

 ...

 printers.Add(new Printer("printer6", 0.25M));
```

Comment: Resize creates new a copies all the contents of the old array into the new one.  It doesn't resize the original array.

Comment: @Fran: you are quite right (that's why we pass the array with `ref` when we call `Array.Resize`). However, this underhood behaviour, IMHO, doesn't matter much: we get the array with its `Length` increased and we know that the arrays are not supposed to change their sizes (so we should not use `Array.Resize` frequently)

Answer (score 1):

Arrays have fixed size - after you created array with size 10 you can't add  one more element (to make size 11).

Use `List<Printer>`:

```
List<Printer> printers = new List<Printer>();
printers.Add(new Printer("printer2", 0.08M));
//add all items
```

Also you can access elements by index:

```
var element = printers[0];
```

Using `List` you can change its size, add and remove elements.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are fixed length.  You need to copy the values into a new array or use an List, List<>, or ArraryList.

Comment: No, they are not immutable. They just have a fixed length. Two different things.

Comment: true.  updating answer.

Comment: ArrayList is pretty much outdated and we shouldn't advise using it. List<T> is the way to go.

Comment: Yes.  I prefer stingy typed collections, but it's still part of the framework